# Appendix Section Title

Tags: appendices

I am writing a paper in the "article" document class.

When it proceeds to my appendix, I would like the two sections to have titles to appear as "Appendix A. Some notation" and "Appendix B. Some more notation". So I trited

```
\appendix                                     
\section{Some notation}
\section{Some more notation}
```

However, I got "A Some notation" and "B Some more notation" as titles. How can I fix this problem?

I read through old relevant threads, but the answers do not seem to work well.

Comment: Please edit your post to provide a complete, small document people can copy-paste-compile. That is a lot more useful than a mere fragment. In what way didn't they work well? What specifically did you try?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `title` option and the `appendices` environment of the `appendix` package can do that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{title 1}
\section{title 2}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Some Notation}

\section{Some More Notation}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if I want a period (as OP)? [Appendix A. Some notation] instead of [Appendix A Some notation]?

Comment: You can add this, just after `begin{appendices}`: `\makeatletter
 \def\@seccntformat{\appendixname\ %
 \csname thesection\endcsname. \quad}
\makeatother`.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify, maybe in your answer or something? It doesn't quite work when I paste, I must do something wrong. Should there be a % there?

Comment: @Seub: Indeed, in my code there is a % at the end of the line (to prevent some spurious space or any other side effects), and I didn't notice that in comments, line breaks disappeared.

Comment: This solution works only for article document class and doesn't work for other document classes.

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour: You should ask a question with a compilable code. There are various  possibilities to solve this problem.