# Show "Appendix A" instead of "A" in the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendix

As the chapters are numbered in TOC (table of contents) the Appendices are lettered. I want to change that from a single letter "A" to "Appendix A".

A Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{MWE}
\author{John D.}
\date{February 2020}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{sections/Introduction}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\maketitle
\chapter{This is a section}
\section{This is a subsection}
Some random content
\appendix
\chapter{Numbers}
\section{Numbers 1}
\chapter{Code}
\section{Code 1}

\end{document}
```

> This will Produce:
>   [MWE example](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vdwybqkfvcmx)

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226497/134144 might be useful.

Comment: Update: I edited MWE: @leandriis I am using a different document class, {\documentclass{article}} but {\documentclass{scrreprt}}. Therefore, appendices are classified as chapters. I tried what it is in the link but did not work!

Comment: Do you just want to change the appearance in the table of contents or also in the document itself?

Comment: @leandriis  "Appendix A" should be shown only in the TOC. In the document  "A. Appendix name".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a new TOC style entry `appendixchapter` using the prefix:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer
\newcommand\entrywithprefix[2]{#1~#2}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter,
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\appendixname}
]{chapter}{appendixchapter}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{appendixchapter}{#1}{#2}}
    {}{\PatchFailedII}%
  }{}{\PatchFailedI}

\title{MWE}
\author{John D.}
\date{February 2020}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
Some random content
\appendix
\chapter{Numbers}
\section{Numbers 1}
\chapter{Code}
\section{Code 1}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

---

With older KOMA-Script versions use

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=1.5em,
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\appendixname}
]{chapter}{appendixchapter}
```

---

If you are using **numbered bookmarks**:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter,
  dynnumwidth,
]{chapter}{appendixchapter}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
  {%
    \Ifstr{#1}{}
      {\addtocentrydefault{appendixchapter}{}{#2}}
      {\addtocentrydefault{appendixchapter}{\appendixname~#1}{#2}}%
  }{}{\PatchFailedII}%
}{}{\PatchFailedI}

\title{MWE}
\author{John D.}
\date{February 2020}

\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
Some random content
\appendix
\chapter{Numbers}
\section{Numbers 1}
\chapter{Code}
\section{Code 1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much. It was a smooth and easy solution! I added the new TOC style entry in my preamble, the first solution suggested, and it worked fine.

Comment: I just noticed that: It is showed right in the TOC but, In the bookmarks of PDF it is shown as a regular chapter. Is there a way to show it some way in the bookmarks of PDF?

Comment: See my updated answer. But there was neither package `hyperref` nor package `bookmark` in your MWE.

Comment: I used your updated version. It is shown as I want in TOC and pdf bookmark section. However, when I use the `bookmark` package I get an error: Missing `begin{document}` in the preamble. Note: I had `hyperref` package in my `preamble` since in the beginning.

Comment: Solved: First Thank you @esdd for the code. Everything is perfect in your code but I have different files for preamble, for `main.tex` and the `chapters`. finally, `\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}` should be the last thing added to preamble... literally the last, just before `\begin{document}`