# How do I get "Appendix" to appear in each appendix section title?

Tags: appendix

I am writing a document in Latex. I would like the word "Appendix" to appear in each section title. For example, the first section should be: "Appendix A: Proofs". Unfortunately, "Appendix" does not appear in the current titles: for example, the current title of the first section is just "A: Proofs".

Is there an easy way to fix this? Unfortunately, none of the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226481/appendix-section-title) worked (I have no idea why).

Here is a minimal(-ish) working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,mathtools,natbib, xcolor,setspace,comment,pdflscape,array, parskip, booktabs, bbm, titlesec, lipsum, footmisc, color, amsthm, tikz, subfig}

\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont \scshape}{}{0em}{}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{}

\begin{appendices}

\textsc{Appendices.}

\section{Proofs}\label{app_sec_proofs}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this is an incompatibility of packages `titlesec` and `appendix`. Without `titlesec` it works. However, you can add a generic hook to change the `\section` formatting with `titlesec`, whenever environment `appendices` starts:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,mathtools,natbib,xcolor,setspace,comment,pdflscape,array, parskip,booktabs, bbm}
\usepackage{titlesec}% the only relevant package beside appendix
%\usepackage{ lipsum, footmisc, color, amsthm, tikz, subfig}

\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont \scshape}{}{0em}{}

\AddToHook{env/appendices/begin}{%
  \titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \scshape}{\sectionname~\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
}

\usepackage[title,titletoc,page]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{appendices}

\textsc{Appendices.}

\section{Proofs}\label{app_sec_proofs}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `:` instead of `.` and option `page` instead of a handmade page title:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,mathtools,natbib,xcolor,setspace,comment,pdflscape,array, parskip,booktabs, bbm}
\usepackage{titlesec}% the only relevant package beside appendix
%\usepackage{ lipsum, footmisc, color, amsthm, tikz, subfig}

\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont \scshape}{}{0em}{}

\AddToHook{env/appendices/begin}{%
  \titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \scshape}{\sectionname~\thesection:}{0.5em}{}
}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Proofs}\label{app_sec_proofs}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note, redefining `\appendixname` to an empty string, does not make sense, if you want "Appendix" prefixes in the table of contents or the titles, because options `title` and `titletoc` uses exactly, this `\appendixname`. For this reason, I've removed your `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{}`.

If you want to change the title "Appendices" either in the ToC or of the appendices page, see `\appendixtocname` and `\appendixpagename` in the `appendix` user guide.

For an alternative suggestion using `scrartcl` instead of `article` and package `appendix` see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700611/277964).

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions! I see that you have deleted: \renewcommand{\appendixname}{}. When I added this back (in order to get rid of the "Appendices" title which otherwise shows up at the start), the problem re-appears. Do you know if it's possible to solve my problem without re-introducing "Appendices" at the start?

Comment: @afreelunch Not quite clear, what you are talking about. If you don't want the "Appendices" remove the `page` option in the second example and the `\textsc{Appendices}` in the first example. Redefining `\appendixname` to remove "Appendices" does not make sense, because `\appendixname` by default is not "Appendices", but "Appendix". [If you have more follow-up questions please ask a new question.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/277964).

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a little confused -- it all seems to work!